# WPF Binding with ElementName doesn't update the value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I bind a Label to the SelectedItem of a ComboBox of the user's accounts. Depending on what you select, the label shows the corresponding balance of that account. It shows the balance of the different accounts just perfectly, but when i check that the amount, the user types in, doesn't exceed his balance of selected account, the balance never changes. Let's say Account1 has a balance of 1500 and Account2 has a balance of 4000. Selecting Account1 shows 1500 in the label, selecting Account2 shows 4000 in the label.

But the Balance property in my ViewModel stays 4000 no matter which account i select.

I use Caliburn.Micro to help with the MVVM part.

My Label:

```
<Label x:Name="Balance"
                   Content="{Binding ElementName=Sender, Path=SelectedItem.Balance, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                   Language="da-DK"
                   ContentStringFormat="{}{0:C}"
                   Style="{StaticResource InputBoxPayments}"/>
```

My ComboBox

```
<xctk:WatermarkComboBox x:Name="Sender"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Sender, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccountNmb, Mode=OneTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedAccountNmb, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    SelectedValuePath="AccountNmb"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="AccountName"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    Watermark="Vælg din konto..."
                                    Style="{StaticResource InputBoxPayments}"/>
```

My ViewModel

```
        private string _accountNmb;
        private string _accountType;
        private string _accountName;
        private decimal _balance;
        private BindingList<AccountModel> _sender = new BindingList<AccountModel>();
        private string _selectedAccountNmb;
        private decimal _amount;
        private string _note;
        private string _receiver;

        public string AccountNmb
        {
            get { return _accountNmb; }
            set
            {
                _accountNmb = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => AccountNmb);
            }
        }
        public string AccountType
        {
            get { return _accountType; }
            set
            {
                _accountType = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => AccountType);
            }
        }
        public string AccountName
        {
            get { return _accountName; }
            set
            {
                _accountName = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => AccountName);
            }
        }
        public decimal Balance
        {
            get { return _balance; }
            set
            {
                _balance = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Balance);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanMakePayment);
            }
        }
        public BindingList<AccountModel> Sender
        {
            get { return _sender; }
            set
            {
                _sender = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Sender);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanMakePayment);
            }
        }
        public string SelectedAccountNmb
        {
            get { return _selectedAccountNmb; }
            set
            {
                _selectedAccountNmb = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedAccountNmb);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanMakePayment);
            }
        }
        public decimal Amount
        {
            get { return _amount; }
            set
            {
                _amount = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Amount);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanMakePayment);
            }
        }
        public string Note
        {
            get { return _note; }
            set
            {
                _note = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Note);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanMakePayment);
            }
        }
        public string Receiver
        {
            get { return _receiver; }
            set
            {
                _receiver = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Receiver);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanMakePayment);
            }
        }

        public bool CanMakePayment
        {
            get
            {
                bool output = false;

                if (SelectedAccountNmb?.Length > 0 &&
                    Note?.Length > 0 &&
                    Receiver?.Length > 0 &&
                    SelectedAccountNmb != Receiver &&
                    Amount > 0 &&
                    Amount <= Balance) // This is where i make sure the amount the user types in doesn't exceed his balance.
                {
                    output = true;
                }

                return output;
            }
        }

// Omitted rest of the file
```

Comment: Don't bind SelectedItem and SelectedValue at the same time. Use only SelectedValue in conjunction with SelectedValuePath. As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in all your Bindings is pointless. It has no effect on OneWay Bindings like that of ItemsSource. For SelectedValue, it is set by default.

Comment: Why do you expect Balance in your viewmodel to change?  Your label just displays the value, The combobox doesn't set the value.  Also. It's a bad idea to use bindlinglist in wpf. Unless they fixed them quite recently there are a couple of bugs in wpf usage.  I recommend you get used to working with observablecollection instead.

Comment: @Andy I see what you mean, my bad. I'm using ObserableCollections now :)

Comment: How would i go about using the Balance value from the selected account in the obserablecollection?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "using". You can bind the selecteditem to a property and do something on change of that by acting in the setter.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30564.wpf-uneventful-mvvm.aspx#Select_From_List_IndexChanged  Or you could make the selectedvalue bind to some other property if you're essentially picking a value out a list.

Comment: @Andy After giving it some thought,  i need to bind AccountNmb and Balance at the same time. I haven't been able to find an example of how to do this.

Comment: I guess you probably need the user to type in account number or search on something like say company name and postcode. Get the customer or company or whatever this is. Then set the balance. It seems odd that a combo is involved in any of this though.

Answer (score 0):

In your Combobox, `SelectedItem` is `SelectedAccountNmb` that it is a string property; and in your Label's content you're binding to your Combobox `SelectedItem` that is `string` and no have `Balance`.

You can do this:

```
  public AccountNmb SelectedAccountNmb
    {
        get { return _selectedAccountNmb; }
        set
        {
            _selectedAccountNmb = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedAccountNmb);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanMakePayment);
        }
    }
```

And you don't need to bind `SelectedValue` in your Combobox because you can get value from `SelectedAccountNmb` property